# Is religious ground valid for holding against organ donation?

Tags: teaching

I've heard people not opting for organ donation on religious grounds. I mean, obviously, it's a personal choice and I respect religious or other objections, but her justification "I want to rest in peace, not in pieces," just genuinely confused me, especially given her chosen course of study.

so can you please give me an insight as to how Hinduism philosophy and texts will respond to this question?

Comment: An enlightened sage is ready to give up his body for welfare of humanity because they know they are Atman not the material body. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dadhichi gave his life and spinal chord for making of Indra's Vajra and defeating Vritra. Thats why a sage or yogi is buried because he is unattached to body while a normal man who thinks he is body in ego has funeral pyre after death and ritual for peace of his Atman for 13 days.